# Model id not saving on the creation of a comment. How to correctly save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got three models set up. Users, guides, and comments. Users have many guides and comments. Guides belong to users and have many comments. Comments belong to users and guides.

When I run `Comment.last.user` in the console, it returns the information pertaining to the user. However, when I run `Comment.last.guide` in the console, it returns `nil`. Something is going wrong with the creation of the comment.

The models all have the classic `has_many` and `belongs_to` relationships set up, so I'll omit those from here. Here is the comments controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_comment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /comments
  # GET /comments.json
  def index
    @comments = Comment.all
  end

  # GET /comments/1
  # GET /comments/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /comments/new
  def new
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  # GET /comments/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /comments
  # POST /comments.json
  def create
    @comment = current_user.comments.build(comment_params)


    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @comment }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /comments/1
  # PATCH/PUT /comments/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.update(comment_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @comment, notice: 'Comment was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /comments/1
  # DELETE /comments/1.json
  def destroy
    @comment.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to comments_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_comment
      @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:body, :user_id, :guide_id)
    end
end
```

Here is the comments migration:

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.text :body
      t.references :user, index: true
      t.references :guide, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Log output when creating comment:

```
Started POST "/comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-08 08:30:54 -0500
Processing by CommentsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"D2BvBIgU+tniZvr2NgQE/TpHY6J2xHOUm701jqTcJ9A=", "comment"=>{"body"=>"NitinJ Sample Comment", "user_id"=>"some value", "guide_id"=>"some value"}, "commit"=>"Create Comment"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (21.7ms)  INSERT INTO "comments" ("body", "created_at", "guide_id", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["body", "NitinJ Sample Comment"], ["created_at", Wed, 08 Jan 2014 13:30:54 UTC +00:00], ["guide_id", 0], ["updated_at", Wed, 08 Jan 2014 13:30:54 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 1]]
   (21.0ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/guides/1-attack
Completed 302 Found in 53ms (ActiveRecord: 43.1ms)


Started GET "/guides/1-attack" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-08 08:30:54 -0500
Processing by GuidesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1-attack"}
  Guide Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "guides".* FROM "guides" WHERE "guides"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "1-attack"]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "guides".* FROM "guides" WHERE "guides"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "1-attack"]]
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Comment Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."guide_id" = ?  [["guide_id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Rendered comments/_form.html.erb (6.6ms)
  Rendered guides/show.html.erb within layouts/application (18.9ms)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Calling #sum with a block is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 4.1. If you want to perform sum calculation over the array of elements, use `to_a.sum(&block)`. (called from _app_views_layouts__navbar_html_erb__2351226726967046587_2202447400 at /Users/DylanRichards/Desktop/runescapeguides/app/views/layouts/_navbar.html.erb:35)
  Guide Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "guides".* FROM "guides" WHERE "guides"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."votable_id" = ? AND "votes"."votable_type" = ? AND "votes"."vote_flag" = 't' AND "votes"."vote_scope" IS NULL  [["votable_id", 1], ["votable_type", "Guide"]]
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."votable_id" = ? AND "votes"."votable_type" = ? AND "votes"."vote_flag" = 'f' AND "votes"."vote_scope" IS NULL  [["votable_id", 1], ["votable_type", "Guide"]]
  Rendered layouts/_navbar.html.erb (7.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 54ms (Views: 47.8ms | ActiveRecord: 1.5ms)
```

Second log output

```
Started POST "/guides/1-attack/comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-08 08:52:29 -0500
Processing by CommentsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"D2BvBIgU+tniZvr2NgQE/TpHY6J2xHOUm701jqTcJ9A=", "comment"=>{"body"=>"Another sample NitinJ comment.", "user_id"=>"some value", "guide_id"=>"some value"}, "commit"=>"Create Comment", "guide_id"=>"1-attack"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 69ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:27:in `create'


  Rendered /Users/DylanRichards/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/DylanRichards/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.7ms)
  Rendered /Users/DylanRichards/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendered /Users/DylanRichards/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (21.7ms)
```

Comment: paste the params you are receiving in create action

Comment: Isn't that already included in the comments controller? @NitinJ

Comment: nop i needed that from your logs

Comment: Hmm... How do I find that information?

Comment: in your logs/devlopment.log file or you can see on your terminal in which you are running server

Comment: Updated original post with log output.

Comment: check this `INSERT INTO "comments" ("body", "created_at", "guide_id", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["body", "NitinJ Sample Comment"], ["created_at", Wed, 08 Jan 2014 13:30:54 UTC +00:00], ["guide_id", 0], ["updated_at", Wed, 08 Jan 2014 13:30:54 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 1]]` the guide_id is `0`

Comment: why do not you try nested resources . so you do not need to pass guide_id in the form

Comment: Is it as simple as `resources :guides do` (newline) `resources :comments` (newline) `end`?

Comment: Your guid_id passed from forms is 0 - investigate why!

Comment: yes and in your create action first statement should be `params[:comments][:guide_id] = params[:guide_id]`

Comment: @NitinJ - Does there have to be anything before `params` in that last statement you just gave me? Tried it out and am getting

undefined method comments_path' for #<#<Class:0x000001035e4198>:0x000001035e7be0>

On `  <%= simple_form_for(@comment) do |f| %>`

Comment: simple_form_for([@guide, @comment]) where @guide should contain the guide object you want to assign

Comment: run rake routes on your terminal and you can see that your routes has been updated now

Comment: I see that the routes has been updated. But that change brings up another error... undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass - 

On `params[:comments][:guide_id] = params[:guide_id]`

That's the create action of the comment controller.

Comment: I'll leave the log output again.

Comment: Done. I think I see the problem, though. The ID of the guide is set to `1-attack`. Attack is the name of the guide. I followed a RailsCasts tutorial involving how to get the model name into the name url. Maybe that's what's interfering with it.

Comment: Yeah. Getting same error regardless, @NitinJ

Comment: I'm going to create a new question.

Comment: are you using friendly_id

Comment: Nope. I just overwrote the to_param method

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44790/discussion-between-nitinj-and-dylan-richards)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this `<%= f.association :guide, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => @guide.id }%>`